# How can I create a 2D ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have the following sample data -->

Physics --> 93
Chemistry --> 72
Mathematics --> 84
Biology --> 67
English --> 78

I want to store this data in an `ArrayList` (because I want to make it resizable)

Then I want to print it out in console.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tenfour04 indicates, this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in that the most suitable data structure is not a list at all, but a map:

```
val marks = mapOf("Physics" to 93, "Chemistry" to 72,
                  "Mathematics" to 84, "Biology" to 67,
                  "English" to 78)

for ((subject, mark) in marks)
    println("Subject --> $subject, Mark --> $mark")
```

In addition to the more natural-looking and concise code, this ensures that you don't store the same subject twice, and that each subject present has exactly one mark.  (A list wouldn't be able to express or enforce those conditions.)  It gives the right types (a `String` subject, and an `Int` mark that you can do arithmetic on if you want, e.g. to calculate an average).   And it's much more efficient at looking up a particular subject.

And, like lists, maps are resizable: if you make it a mutable map then you can add, update, and remove items as much as you want.

Regarding lists: Kotlin does not have multi-dimensional lists or arrays.  Instead, it has lists *of* lists, which are a rough approximation, but more complex to set up and update, and slightly less efficient.  There are certainly situations where they're needed — but this isn't one of them!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to create an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`

Each element of outer `ArrayList` will itself be an `ArrayList` of size 2 storing `Subject` and `Marks`

```
fun main() {
    val arrayList: ArrayList<ArrayList<Any>> = arrayListOf(arrayListOf("Biology", 74),
            arrayListOf("Chemistry", 49), arrayListOf("Physics", 92), arrayListOf("Mathematics", 82))
    
    for (element in arrayList) {
        println("Subject --> ${element.get(0)}, Marks --> ${element.get(1)}")
    }
}
```

Console Output -->

```
Subject --> Biology, Marks --> 74
Subject --> Chemistry, Marks --> 49
Subject --> Physics, Marks --> 92
Subject --> Mathematics, Marks --> 82
```

Comment: This is a poor approach. Using a 2D list instead of a Map is needless complexity, and you lose type information.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Still this shows that it is possible to create 2D list. I searched for an hour in this site but found no question that covers this. So I felt that this question needs to be there for sake of completeness